# Zxing barcode plugin phonegap, encode code128?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, zxing, barcode-scanner

Can code128 and code39 be encoded with zxing barcode plugin, if so, how?

I was searching through the internet and few said that is possible few not, don't realy know :)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

To encode the data into Code_128 Fomat, some change needs to be done in zxing barcode plugin

1. Navigate to CaptureActivity in Eclipse.
2. src -> com.google.zxing.client.android.encode -> QRCodeEncoder.java
3. Replace all the 'BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE ' with BarcodeFormat.CODE_128

~Anandaraja

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to [this barcode plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner), which appears to use Zxing 2.1, then yes you can use `CODE_128` and `CODE_39` as per the `README`.  The `README` also give examples of how to use.

Comment: I tried to change the example code from the link but somehow it doesn't work. If this is method: encode(type, data, success, fail), then type code for code128 must be BarcodeScanner.Encode.CODE_128?

Comment: Correct, are you using Cordova 2.x or Cordova 3.0?

Comment: i'm using Cordova 2.1.

Comment: It looks like if you're using Cordova 2.0-2.1, you have to use the 2.0 directory for the plugin.  And according to the docs there, the 2.0 directory does not have ZXing.  If you update to Cordova 2.2, then you'll be able to use the 2.2 directory which does have ZXing.  If you don't know how to upgrade, check out [the guide here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_upgrading_android_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20Android), and look at upgrading to 2.2 from 2.1.